# From the mountain top to the coast.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

From a mountain top lead to ways to the (sea)coast. Neither way goes below of the sea level or over of the mountain top. Show that Adam and Barbara can go on the roads from the mountain top to the sea level(during the road their altitude/elevation are the same.)(The ways have finite incline-slope sections.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, it's probably related to the graph theory, at least I assume it.

Comment: I think you confused the problem statement.  Do you want to show that if they take two different paths, there will be a point where their elevations are the same?  If so, this is just the mean value theorem (nothing to do with graphs).

Comment: the exercise says that their elevations are always the same

Comment: Ok, then you should clarify the question in the post.  As it stands, it seems to say "there are two roads from the mountain top to the coast... show that you can take the roads from the mountain top to the coast".

Comment: I mean Adam is going on a way and Barbara is going on the other way

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking.  You should edit the question statement to make it as clear as possible for others.

Comment: The hypotheses appear to be intended to imply that each road can be described by a differentiable function $f$ giving altitude as a function of distance $x$ travelled from the mountain top, a function whose value never exceeds its initial value $f(0)$ and is never negative. If you are to prove that Adam and Barbara can go in such a way that they are always at the same altitude, you have to allow one or both of them to reverse direction if necessary. (E.g., if Adam’s path descends linearly, while Barbara’s descends, then rises, then descends again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with graph theory by only considering the local extrema.
By abstracting away some unnecessary details and some scaling we may assume that
Adam starts at $(-1,1)$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$), Barbara starts at $(1,1)$, and they must meet at $(0,0)$.
Adam's road will be a continuous function from $f:[-1,0]\to[0,1]$ with $f(-1)=1$ and $f(0)=0$ and
Barbara's road will be a continuous function from $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with $g(1)=1$ and $g(0)=0$.
Furthermore we will require the functions to have only a finite number of local extrema.

This gives us a number of road segments between the extrema, say Adam's segments are $r_1,\ldots,r_p$
and Barbara's segments are $s_1,\ldots,s_q$ (Adam starts at the beginning of $r_1$ and travels to the end of $r_p$,
Barbara starts at the end of $s_q$ and travels to the start of $s_1$).

We define a graph whose vertices are the pairs $(r_i,s_j)$.
$r_i$ corresponds to some vertical segment $[x_i,y_i]$ and $s_j$ corresponds to some vertical segment $[a_j,b_j]$.
The idea is, that these pairs indicate the segments on which Adam and Barbara can be simultaneously without
violating the condition that they are on the same height
(this implies that we can remove pairs where $y_i<a_j$ or $b_j<x_i$, but that is irrelevant).

We draw an edge between a pair $(r_i,s_j)$ and $(r_{i'},s_{j'})$ if an immediate transition between
those pairs is possible, i.e. if Adam can go from $r_i$ to $r_{i'}$ while simultaneously
Barbara goes from $s_i$ to $s_{i'}$, both remaining on the same altitude.

Now the proof consists of showing that all vertices have even degree, except the pair $(r_1,s_q)$
(the beginpoint) and the pair $(r_p,s_1)$ (the endpoint), which have odd degree.
The component containing the beginpoint must have an even number of vertices of odd degree,
so it must also contain the endpoint, which implies that the graph contains a path between
beginpoint and endpoint, which finishes the proof.

Actually proving that the degree parities behave as claimed, requires a small but simple case
analysis. I'll show that the beginpoint has odd degree, you can probably fill in the rest.

Let $r_1$ correspond to the (vertical) segment $[x_1,1]$ and $s_q$ to the vertical segment $[a_q,1]$.
Note that both Adam and Barbara necessarily start their trip by going down.

If $x_1<a_q$, that means that Adam cannot reach the end of its first segment before Barbara
already needs to use a second segment, so the only possible immediate transition is from
$(r_1,s_q)$ to $(r_1,s_{q-1})$ (and this transition is always possible, although the altitude
requirement it may force Adam to "turn around" when Barbara enters her second segment).

The case $x_1>a_q$ is similar.

If $x_1=a_q$ there are four sub-options.
If Adams second segment goes further down, but Barbara's second segment goes back up,
the only possible immediate transition is to $(r_1,s_{q-1})$ (Barbara can continue,
but Adam must turn around) and similarly if Barbara's second segment goes further down,
but Adam's second segment goes back up. So we find degree 1 in these cases.

If the next segments for both Adam and Barbara go further down we have three possibilities:
Adam and Barbara can both go further down (transition is to $(r_2,s_{q-1})$)
or Adam can go further down while Barbara turns around (transition is to $(r_2,s_q)$)
or Barbara can go further down while Adam turns around (transition is to $(r_1,s_{q-1})$).
Of course they can both turn around, but this does not lead to a new vertex.
So we find degree 3 in this case and similarly if the next segments for both Adam and Barbara
go back up.